# Check if an object class is a subclass of another class, but with generics

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection

There has been a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find any with generics playing a role

```
abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract T getT();
    public void someMethod(Object value){
        if(A.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())
            // either B or C work, as expected
        if(A<Long>.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass()) // does not compile
            // this should allow classes like B only
    }
}
class B extends A<Long>{
    long id;
    @Override
    public Long getT(){return id;}
}
class C extends A<Integer>{
    int id;
    @Override
    public Integer getT(){return id;}
}
```

What I need is a way to distinguish between B and C when using some method, as shown in the second if

Comment: Some specific cases of this are impossible: for example, in `class D<T> extends A<T>`, a `D<Integer>` cannot be distinguished from a `D<String>`.  Is there a reason you can't write `if(B.class.isAssignableFrom` and the like?

Comment: `public abstract getT();` is not a valid declaration.

Comment: @tgdavies you are correct. I will quickly edit it

Comment: @LouisWasserman I believe you mean why don't I use `value instanceof B`? While I could use, it would make the code a lot messy since I would have to make a new if else in case someone add a new class that extends A

Comment: Add a method `abstract Class<T> getTypeParameter()` to `A<T>` that the subclasses are forced to implement.